# MongoDb text search doesn't return a result

Tags: mongodb

I have the following query

```
db.Profiles.find({  "$text" : { "$search" : "vk" } })
```

It gives me the following result

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55e999a5bd1f3926586799bb"),
    "created" : ISODate("2015-09-04T13:16:21.555Z"),
    "userId" : 4790,
    "email" : "vk@mydomain.com",
    "firstName" : "",
    "lastName" : "",
    "phoneNumber" : "",
    "isUnsubscribed" : false,
    "isAboveLimit" : true,
    "status" : 0,
    "userAgent" : 0,
    "isDeleted" : false,
    "p2l" : [ 
      {
            "listId" : 31613,
            "status" : 25,
            "subscriptionDate" : ISODate("2015-09-17T14:04:33.660Z")
        }
    ],
    "countryId" : 0,
    "cf" : []
}
```

But the following does not

```
db.Profiles.find({  "$text" : { "$search" : "v" }})
```

There are not results.

Answer (score 4):

From [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#match-operation):

> The `$text` operator matches on the complete stemmed word. So if a
>   document field contains the word *blueberry*, a search on the term *blue*
>   will not match. However, blueberry or blueberries will match.

If you want to find the records that contain a `v` in the `email` field, you can do a `$regex` match:

```javascript
db.Profiles.find({  "email" : { "$regex" : /v/ } })
```

Comment: Regex isn't suitable for me because this doen't use indexes

Comment: @MongoUser101 Do you have a source for that statement? http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use states differently, very much so.